# Export a module without named it

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to make a translation module in nodejs that's converting an xml file to a js object.

This is my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translation>
    <title>This is a title</title>
</translation>
```

Here's my module :

```
const xmlJS = require('xml-js');
const fs = require('fs');
let translation = '';

// convert xml to json to js object
fs.readFile( './translation.xml', function(err, data) {
if (err) throw err;

  let convert = xmlJS.xml2json(data, {compact: true, spaces: 2});
  let parse = JSON.parse(convert).translation;
  translation = parse.en;
});

// wait until export, i have to do this cuz converting xml take like 1sec on my computer,
// so if i'm not waiting before the export my module will return me a blank object.
function canIExport() {
  if (translation === '') {
    setTimeout(() => {
      canIExport();
    }, 500);
  } else {
    exports.translation = translation;
  }
}
canIExport();
```

In my app.js :

```
const translation = require('./translation');
```

And here's my probleme, when i try to call some text in my `translation` object
i have to do something like : `translation.translation.title._text`.
I have to do `translation.translation` because my `exports.translation = translation` is putting my var in a sub object of translation (a bit like in Inception).

So how to avoid this and just do something like `translation.title._text` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is XY problem. Asynchronous modification of export object is an antipattern. This will result in race conditions.

Module exports should either be entirely synchronous:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const data = fs.readFileSync( './translation.xml');
...
module.exports = translation;
```

Or a module should export a promise:

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;

module.exports = fs.readFile( './translation.xml')
.then(data => ...);
```

And be used as such:

```
const translationPromise = require('./translation');

translationPromise.then(translation => ...);
```

Comment: Thanks it work. I prefer using the Async module, this is much cleaner to use.

Comment: Yes actually this is for a discord bot so it's ok for a little app like this one.